# How to call block defined as property in another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am calling the block from second class which has been declared and maintained in first class.

In ViewController.h

```
@property (copy) void (^simpleBlock)(NSString*);
```

In View Controller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.simpleBlock = ^(NSString *str)
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello My Name is: %@",str);
    };
}
```

In SecondViewController.m

In ViewDidload

```
ViewController *VC = [[ViewController alloc]init];
VC.simpleBlock(@"Harjot");//bad execution error
```

Please suggest me some solutions because the code is giving me bad execution error.
How can i call the block in any another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the correct way of run the block. However if you try to run a block that is `nil` you'll have a crash - so you should always check that it's not `nil` before calling it:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
if (vc.simpleClock) {
   vc.simpleBlock(@"Harjot");//this will not get called
}
```

The reason why in your case the block is `nil` is because you set it in `viewDidLoad` - however `viewDidLoad` is not called until its view is ready to go on screen. For testing purposes try to move the assignment from `viewDidLoad` to `init` and this should work:

```
- (instancetype)init 
{
   self [super init];
   if (self) {
      _simpleBlock = ^(NSString *str)
      {
          NSLog(@"Hello My Name is: %@",str);
      };
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: What if there is no init method should we add it?